# For Faster-RCNN, is it possible to fine tune existing model if I want to also specify new anchor box scale and aspect ratio?

Tags: computer-vision, conv-neural-network, object-detection

For Faster-RCNN, is it possible to fine tune existing model (say trained with Coco dataset) to detect a single class of objects, say traffic lights, if I want to also specify new anchor box scale and aspect ratio most suitable for detecting traffic signs?

The reason is the default anchor boxes (for region proposal network) are not good at detecting very small objects like traffic lights from far away.

Specifically, I want to avoid retraining the model from scratch but I am unsure if fine tuning is possible if I want to specify different anchor boxes scale and aspect ratio.